# jQuery - How to Prevent Animation Queue Buildup with Double Animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

I was taking a look at this tutorial here to prevent animation buildups:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

My situation:
I am doing a double animation like this below, and would like the prevent the animation build up. Since I have 2 animations going, it seems it ignores the .stop(). What can be done to prevent this? I have tried .stop() on both .animate and if I do that it stops animating...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop()
        .animate(
            { left: 200 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
            })
        .animate(
            { top: 200 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
            });
} , function() {
    $(this).stop()
        .animate(
            { left: 0 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
            })
        .animate(
            { top: 0 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
            });
});
```

});

Any help will be greatly aprecaited!!

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
$(this).stop(true);
```

From [`stop()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop):

> Stops all the currently running
>   animations on all the specified
>   elements.

**Note:** "currently running" not queued, as you're experiencing. For that supply the parameter:

> ```
> clearQueue (Optional) Boolean
> ```
>
> A Boolean (true/false) that when set
>   to true clears the animation queue,
>   effectively stopping all queued
>   animations.

Also you can supply the second parameter that will shortcut to animation completion rather than cancelling it if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) which will not break the layout.